# Records correlation/clustering using Hadoop

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, machine-learning, data-mining, cluster-analysis

Our Hadoop cluster ingests several terabytes of web logs daily. Each log record contains information like user IP address, cookie ID and so on. However, different IP addresses and cookie IDs can correspond to one physical user (home/work computers etc). We designed a function that calculates matching score for any pair of records, the higher score means higher probability that both records correspond to one physical user.

The goal is to split all records into groups that presumably correspond to one physical user using the scoring function and mark all records in a group by unique group ID (i.e. physical user ID). What is the best way to implement this logic using Hadoop/Mahout?

Answer (score 2):

For a start, I'm going to assume that you know how to chain MapReduce jobs.  If not, see http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#chaining for details.

Second, I will assume that you have a distributed key/value store available to you, like Cassandra.

Third, your scoring function does not make sense to me.  I wouldn't think that "one record from here, one record from there" would let you know that they are the same person.  I could believe that "records from here compared to records from there = estimate of whether or not the same person".  So I will assume, contrary to your description, that this is how your scoring function actually works.

Now what would be a theoretically nice way to solve your problem?

1. Process logs, put into your store a map of unique machine identifier (IP address + cookie) + date range to all logged events.
2. Extract out a list of all unique machine identifiers.  Store that as well.
3. Perform a MapReduce where the map takes a machine identifier, grabs the list of all of the others, and emits all pairs of different machine identifiers with the first less than the second.  The reduce queries for the logged events of each, computes the score, and then if the score is over a threshold emits the data point that the larger machine identifier maps to the smaller one.
4. The output of 3 is piped to a map reduce whose map does nothing, and whose finds for each machine identifier the smallest machine identifier that it maps to.
5. The output of 4 is piped to a map reduce whose map takes a pair (machine identifier, canonical machine identifier), grabs events from the store in #1, and remaps them to (canonical machine identifier, rest of event), and whose reduce stores for a canonical machine identifier (aka group ID), the associated events.  (By date if you want.)

OK, that's a nice theory.  Where does it go wrong?

The problem is that all pairs of identifiers is just too darned many.  That list could wind up being on the order of 10<sup>18</sup>, for each of which you're pulling logs.  Unless you have truly phenomenal hardware, you're going to run out of processing power to calculate that.  Therefore you need to find heuristics to reduce it.

The first, and simplest, is that any identified "these two identifiers map to the same one" should be stored and reused up front wherever possible.

Second, after a large initial job you can probably get away with, "Of all recently created identifiers, what do they map to?"  Those are candidates for addition to your canonical mapping, which you don't want to be always recreating.

Third, I'm sure that you have a notion of "similar record".  So map records to some sort of record group, and then in a reduce have all "small enough" groups map all pairs off to "possibly the same".  Send those pairs into a map reduce that grabs "possibly the same" records and then creates a lookup mapping machine identifier to all "came up possibly the same more than X times".  Save that.  Now repeat the above, except that in step 2 you send a machine identifier to all pairs of itself with a "came up possibly the same" other.  This shortcut will greatly reduce the work.

This is a general strategy which is a lot of work.  Good luck.